# jquery selectedIndex doesn't work

Tags: jquery

i have a from with many select tags , when the user submit the form i want to check if the user choose one option for all the select tags and this is my jquery code

```
$('#apForm select').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.selectedIndex == 0){
                var error = 'fill this please' ;
                $this.next('span').text(error);
                errorCount = errorCount + 1;   
            }
        });
```

and i tried like this

```
$this.attr("selectedIndex")
```

i just give you the piece of my code where my question is
if i should give more code tell me

thank you for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $this = $(this);
if($this.get(0).selectedIndex == 0) {

}
```

or just simple

```
this.selectedIndex; // not $this / $(this)
```

If no `option` it will return `-1`

**[here I showed all above cases](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/HvG99/5/)**

Comment: Or use `this.selectedIndex` directly.

Comment: @Th0rndike i was talken about his code before update , thecodeparadox ,you the one man it works good , but just one thing if the select didn't have any option what sould the code be ? i mean there is no option with the index 0  , i mean the select is empty

Comment: @thecodeparadox yes man it works , thank you , i accept your answer , really thank you

Answer (score 3):

It's this.selectedIndex, not $this.selectedIndex :)

- this is the HTMLDomElement
- $this is jQuery object

Comment: but $this is the same with this , because i wrote var $this  = (this) , am i right or not ?

Comment: @williamkinaan no you wrote $this = $(this);

Comment: OH i though it is the same , anyway your code works  , but i still have a problem , not all my select tags have at least one option , there is some select tags doesn't have any option , so how can i print that error message if there is no option in the select ?

Comment: The selectedIndex would be -1 if none was selected.

Comment: yes thank you it works , i hope i could accept more than one answer , really thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a version of jQuery above 1.6? then you can use

```
if ( $this.prop('selectedindex') == 0 ){ /* handle */ }
```