# Alert if user doesn't select from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to throw an error if a user hits the Submit button without selecting an item from the list.

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/gqpomau2/

**HTML:**

```
<form>
<select id="gender" name="gender">
  <option value="0">Select from dropdown menu</option>
  <option value="Male">Male</option>
  <option value="Female">Female</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
  <button type='submit' onclick='a()'>submit</button>
  <p id='demo'></p>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
if($("#gender").attr("selectedIndex") === 0) {
    alert("You haven't selected anything!");
} else {
  alert ("Yeah you clicked something")
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery selectedIndex doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652063/jquery-selectedindex-doesnt-work)

Comment: `selectedIndex` is a property only, check with `.prop` instead.

Comment: @Teemu Will look into this. I did have this originally but fell down the rabbit hole.

Comment: you can use `.val()` also.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra So this would be `($('#gender:selected').val() == '')`  ?

Comment: `$('#gender').val() === '0'` as that's the value of your default option. Also note that you shouldn't use an inline `onclick` attribute. Not least on a submit button. If you want to perform an action when a form is submit, hook an unobtrusive handler to the `submit` event of that form.

Comment: yes you have `0` value  when text is Select from dropdown menu so copmare selected value with 0